# Laravel - unread message count from controller global

Tags: php, laravel

I have a dashboard where you can see how many unread messages you got, but I want this variable to be used on all pages to create a badge in my navbar. How can I return this variable to all views?

This is my `DashboardController`:

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{

public function index()
{
    $spentAmount = 0;
    $ordersPending = 0;
    $ordersCancelled = 0;
    $ordersCompleted = 0;
    $ordersPartial = 0;
    $ordersInProgress = 0;
    $orders = Auth::user()->orders;
    $ticketIds = Ticket::where(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id])->get()->pluck('id')->toArray();
    $unreadMessages = TicketMessage::where(['is_read' => 0])->whereIn('ticket_id', $ticketIds)->whereNotIn('user_id', [Auth::user()->id])->count();
    $supportTicketOpen = Ticket::where(['status' => 'OPEN', 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id])->count();

    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        if (strtolower($order->status) == 'pending') {
            $spentAmount += $order->price;
            $ordersPending++;
        } elseif (strtolower($order->status) == 'cancelled') {
            $ordersCancelled++;
        } elseif (strtolower($order->status) == 'completed') {
            $spentAmount += $order->price;
            $ordersCompleted++;
        } elseif (strtolower($order->status) == 'partial') {
            $spentAmount += $order->price;
            $ordersCompleted++;
        } elseif (strtolower($order->status) == 'inprogress') {
            $ordersInProgress++;
        }
    }
    return view('dashboard', compact(
        'spentAmount',
        'ordersPending',
        'ordersCancelled',
        'ordersCompleted',
        'unreadMessages',
        'ordersPartial',
        'supportTicketOpen',
        'ordersInProgress'
    ));


}
```

}

Comment: You need to look into view composers - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#sharing-data-with-all-views.

Comment: I guess the easiest would be Middleware or a view composer as suggested above.

Comment: Is it possible to add App classes to the provider?
use App\Ticket;
use App\TicketMessage;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three different ways to solve your challenge

*** Middleware**
*** BaseClass**
*** JavaScript**

the middleware and base controller is similar approach

---

**Middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $notificationCount = 1;// query the database here and get notification for your

    // add $notificationCount to your request instance
    $request->request->add(['notificationCount' => $notificationCount]);

    // call the middleware next method and you are done.
    return $next($request);
}
```

and now now you can attach this middleware in your routes or group of routes

---

**BaseController**

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {

            $notificationCount = 1;// query the database here and get notification for your

            // add $notificationCount to your request instance
            $request->request->add(['notificationCount' => $notificationCount]);

            // call the middleware next method and you are done.
            return $next($request);
        });
    }
}
```

and now you can extends your controller with `MyController` instead of `Controller` and than you can use something like that

```
{{ request('notificationCount') }}
```

---

**Javascript**

Create a function/controller and return the number of notifications to as return

```
class NotificationCounterController extends Controller
{
    function getNotificatioCount()
    {
        $notificationCount = 1;
        return ['count' => $notificationCount];
    }
}
```

and not you can make ajax call in on document load event.

> this is good if want to update notification in every few time. like you can make ajax call in every 5 second.